# generic api consume class in c#

Tags: c#, json, reflection

```
try
            { 
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = GlobalVariables.WebAPI.GetAsync("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees").Result;
                if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {

                    var tupleList = new List<Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>>();
                    var genericList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<object>>(httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                    int _totalColumns = 0;
                    var allowFirst = false;
                    foreach ( var genericObject in genericList)
                    {
                        allowFirst = true;
                        if (allowFirst)
                        { 
                            try
                            {
                                Type type = genericObject.GetType();

                                // Get all public instance properties.
                                // Use the override if you want to classify
                                // which properties to return.
                                foreach (PropertyInfo info in type.GetProperties())
                                {  

                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
```

l dont know if this is possible but am trying to create a generic class to consume api.

the data will only be in form of array objects without inner objects on another object like sample

**sample 1**

```
 [
      {
        "id": "24",
        "employee_name": "Doris Wilder",
        "employee_salary": "85600",
        "employee_age": "23",
        "profile_image": "images/default_profile.png"
      },
      {
        "id": "25",
        "employee_name": "Angelica Ramos",
        "employee_salary": "1200000",
        "employee_age": "47",
        "profile_image": "images/default_profile.png"
      }
    ]
```

Sample Two

```
[
  {
    "project_Id": "24",
    "project_name": "Lorem Ipsum" 
  },
   {
    "project_Id": "25",
    "project_name": "Lorem Ipsum ipsum" 
  }
]
```

Sample 3

```
[
  {
    "Employee_Id": "25",
    "Employee_name": "Sam Doe" 
  },
{
    "Employee_Id": "2",
    "Employee_name": "Jon doe" 
  }
]
```

Upto

```
Sample 20++   ..................:
```

m stack on now determining the number of object propertise and how to store it ?

like sampe 1 has four properties

sample 2 has two properties how best can l do that
and determining how to save it:

Edit

l have more than 20 urls { and likely to increase }are different array of objects what l wanted was not to create Strongly typed class as the data is only used to be rendered on an html table string but all the api values will have 0-100 array of object , thus all l want to know if its possible or l will stick to what l was already doing which was mentioned by @nkosi

Comment: Json.Net is already generic, also this data looks unrelated, whats the use case here?

Comment: If each response is associated with different URLs then what is the problem? create strongly typed models for each type and create a generic response model to hold the expected type when deserializing.

Comment: What you want to achieve exactly? 1 single mapping for all response types? Then you should probably deserialize your json into a dictionary. But again, you need to resolve how to extract variables from it. So the logical solution is to have seperate classes which represents different json structures.

Comment: i updated the info @TheGeneral

Comment: @Nkosi l updated the question

Comment: @EmreSavcı updated question